# Does the TMC5160 track motor position?

Tags: motor-controller, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

It's not clear if the TMC5160 has position tracking internally or if it can be used in substitute of an external encoder.

The data sheet indicates that the driver can both detect stalls and tracks steps via sensing the commuter but requires a minimum rotational velocity (I'm guessing like BLDC speed sensing).

https://www.analog.com/en/products/tmc5160.html

Answer (score 0):

It tracks steps means that you can use it to know how much the angle has *changed*.

Physically impossible to know the absolute position from voltage and current, motors are rotationally symmetrical, so no chip magically does that. And your chip is no exception.

Comment: It would start at a zeroed position but that's not the point, is this tracking feature actually accurate? It's not clear to me if you can really use it for closed loop control or not.

Comment: It's a stepper motor control that can tell you when you missed a step, so, yes, if you can count, you know how many steps you've taken.